# How to keep a sprite from "jumping" more than once in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics, phaser-framework

Let me say that to start, I've already asked this question once. The answer worked fine, but I have been adding code since then and now the previous answer doesn't work.

Before, I had solved this by adding a variable called `skaterTouchingGround`, and setting it to true when the skater had "collided", with the ground (or when he was on the ground). Then, when I made the player jump, after detecting the jump key, `skaterTouchingGround` would be set to false. This no longer works for some reason, so I think I need a new way of limiting my player to one jump before he hits the ground again.

I have tried changing how the variable's value is determined, and changing how the key press is detected.

Here is the game's full code

```
//Configurations for the physics engine
var physicsConfig = {
    default: 'matter',
    matter : {
        gravity: {
            x: 0,
            y: 2.5, // <--This is the only way I could get the skater to roll up the ramp.
        },
        debug: true //CHANGE THIS TO TRUE TO SEE LINES
    }   
}

//Variables for height and width
var gameHeight = 750;
var gameWidth = 3000;

//Game configurations
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1500, //<-- this is the width of what we will see at one time
    height: gameHeight,
    physics: physicsConfig,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }   
}

/* This variable will be used to make sure the skater 
cannot ollie while he is already in the air */
let skaterTouchingGround;

//Start the game
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

//Declare variables so we can access them in all functions
var skater;
var ground;
var sky;

//Score variables
let score = 0;
let scoreBoard;

function preload() {
    //Images
    this.load.image('sky', 'archery_assets/images/sky.png');

    //Load sprites from TexturePacker
    this.load.atlas('sheet', 'skate_assets/sprites.png', 'skate_assets/sprites.json');
    //Load body shapes from PhysicsEditor
    this.load.json('shapes', 'skate_assets/spritesPE.json');
}

function create() {

    //Background
    sky = this.add.image(1500, 325,'sky')
    //Scale the image
    sky.setDisplaySize(gameWidth, gameHeight);

    //Get the hitboxes
    var shapes = this.cache.json.get('shapes');

    //Set world bounds    
    this.matter.world.setBounds(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);

    //Place ground object
    ground = this.matter.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sheet', 'ground', {shape: shapes.ground});
    //Ground is 600x600, so double the x pixels and we get screen width
    ground.setScale(5, 1);
    ground.setPosition(1500, 650);
    //Let the ground detect collisions 
    ground.isSensor(true);

    //Place the ramp
    var ramp = this.matter.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sheet', 'ramp', {shape: shapes.ramp});
    ramp.setPosition(550 + ramp.centerOfMass.x, 250 + ramp.centerOfMass.y);

    //Place a bench
    var bench = this.matter.add.sprite(2000, 200, 'sheet', 'bench', {shapes: shapes.bench});
    bench.setScale(2, 1);
    bench.setPosition(2250 + bench.centerOfMass.x, 50 + bench.centerOfMass.y);

    //Create the skater
    skater = this.matter.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sheet', 'roll/0001', {shape: shapes.s0001});
    skater.setPosition(100 + skater.centerOfMass.x, 200 + skater.centerOfMass.y);

    //Collision filtering
    var staticCategory = this.matter.world.nextCategory();
    ramp.setCollisionCategory(staticCategory);
    ground.setCollisionCategory(staticCategory);
    bench.setCollisionCategory(staticCategory);

    var skaterCategory = this.matter.world.nextCategory();
    skater.setCollisionCategory(skaterCategory);

    //Roll animation
    //Generate the frame names
    var rollFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 1, end: 4, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'roll/'}
    );
    //Create the animation
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'roll', frames: rollFrameNames, frameRate: 16, repeat: -1
    });

    //Push animation
    var pushFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 5, end: 8, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'push/'}
    );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'push', frames: pushFrameNames, frameRate: 16, repeat: 0 
    });

    //Shuvit animation
    var shuvFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 9, end: 12, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'shuv/'}
    );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'shuv', frames: shuvFrameNames, frameRate: 32, repeat: 0 
    });

    //Ollie animation
    var ollieFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 13, end: 20, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'ollie/'}
    );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'ollie', frames: ollieFrameNames, frameRate: 24, repeat: 0
    });

    //Kickflip animation
    var kfFrameNames = this.anims.generateFrameNames(
        'sheet', {start: 21, end: 33, zeroPad: 4,
        prefix: 'kickflip/'}
    );
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'kickflip', frames: kfFrameNames, frameRate: 24, repeat: 0
    });

    //This keeps the rolling animation going once the push animation is done
    skater.on('animationcomplete', () => {
        skater.anims.play('roll');
    });

    //Input for arrowkeys
    this.arrowKeys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys({
        up: 'up',
        down: 'down',
        left: 'left',
        right: 'right'
    }); 

    //Input for WASD keys
    this.WASDkeys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys({
        W: 'W',
        A: 'A',
        S: 'S',
        D: 'D'
    });

    //Spacebar
    this.spacebar = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.SPACE);

    //Camera to follow the skater
    this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, 3000, gameHeight);
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(skater);

    //Detect the player's collision with the ground
    this.matter.world.on('collisionactive', (skater, ground) => {
        skaterTouchingGround = true;
    });

    //Scoreboard
    scoreBoard = this.add.container(10, 50);
    scoreText = this.add.text(10, 50, "SCORE: 0", {fontSize: '56px', color: '#fff'});

    //Add the text to the container which will be our scoreboard
    scoreBoard.add(scoreText);

    //Make the scoreboard follow the player
    this.tweens.add({
        targets: scoreBoard,
        ease: 'Linear',
        duration: 1,
        delay: 1,
        yoyo: false,
        repeat: -1
    });

}

function update() {
    //Set variable for player movement
    var pushSpeed = 0;
    var ollie = 0;

    //Make sure the player isn't doing anything if he's upside down, or crashed
    let skaterCrashed;

    if (skater.angle > -50 && skater.angle < 5) {
        skaterCrashed = false;
    }
    else {
        skaterCrashed = true;
    }

    //Pushing
    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.spacebar) && !skaterCrashed && skaterTouchingGround) {
        //Increase speed
        pushSpeed = 15;

        //Move player
        skater.setVelocityX(pushSpeed);

        //Play push animation
        skater.anims.play('push');
    }

    //Ollie
    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.arrowKeys.up) && skaterTouchingGround) {
        //Set this to false, because we are about to jump
        skaterTouchingGround = false;

        //Set ollie power
        ollie = -15;

        //Set skate velocity
        skater.setVelocityY(ollie);

        //Play the ollie animation
        skater.anims.play('ollie');

        //Scoring for ollie
        score += 1;
    }

    //Shuvit
    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.arrowKeys.down)) {
        //Play the shuvit animation
        skater.anims.play('shuv');

        //Scoring for shuv
        score += 3;
    }

    //Kickflip
    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(this.WASDkeys.W)  && skaterTouchingGround) {
        //Reset variable since we are jumping
        skaterTouchingGround = false

        //Set jump height
        ollie = -14

        //Move the player
        skater.setVelocityY(ollie);

        //Play animation
        skater.anims.play('kickflip');

        //Scoring for kickflip
        score += 10;
    }

    //Tilting backwards in the air
    if (this.arrowKeys.left.isDown && !skaterTouchingGround) {
        //Be able to turn backwards so you don't flip
        skater.angle -= 3 ;
    }
    //Tilting forwards in the air
    if (this.arrowKeys.right.isDown && !skaterTouchingGround) {
        //Be able to turn forwards so you don't flip
        skater.angle += 3 ;
    }

    //Move the scoreboard
    scoreText.x = skater.body.position.x - 200;
    scoreText.setText("SCORE : " + score);

}
```

I just need the player to not be able to double jump, and to only be able to jump again after he has hit the ground.

Comment: I checked for 30 minutes tonight. I haven't been able to debug it. Could you give me more details on what you added? Also did you remove some code?

Comment: I’m not sure what I did, but I have since fixed it. Sorry I did not update you!!!

Comment: Oh nice! Haha it happens. Make sure to answer your own question then ;) cheers!